# How to add full permission to network service through C#

Tags: c#, permissions, network-service

I'm trying to give Network service full access to one folder that is already existing. Is it possible to get it done through code?

Comment: Feasibility aside, you shouldn't be doing it - modifying inbuilt system accounts is a bad approach.

Comment: The security identifier[SID] for known accounts is described in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers). And you could use this [ICACLs](https://superuser.com/questions/1019558/how-to-add-a-sid-to-a-folder-permissions)  to provide permissions to specific folder.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, thanks for the input, let me try out what you shared.